# Nominativ-Ergänzung und Passiv

Tags: grammar, expletiva

Im Deutschen ist es möglich, einen Passivsatz ohne Subjekt zu bilden:

> Hier wird gearbeitet.

Das ist immer dann der Fall, wenn die Aktiv-Situation intransitiv ist. Die Abwesenheit eines Passivsubjekts ist im Grunde also nur logisch … kein Objekt im Aktiv – kein Subjekt im Passiv. Sätze wie der obige sind in vielen Sprachen unmöglich. Daher ist es für viele verwirrend, kein Subjekt zu haben, zumal es da ist, wenn man den Satz umstellt:

> Es wird hier gearbeitet.

Ein Freund von mir stellte eine ähnliche Frage im Unterricht und die Lehrerin erklärte nach einiger Diskussion schließlich folgendes:

> Mit Wasser muss gespart werden.

*Mit Wasser* sei eine „Nominativ-Ergänzung“.
Ich halte das für Unfug, aber hier meine Fragen:

1. Wenn diese Erklärung stimmt und „mit Wasser“ in dem Beispiel eine Nominativ-Ergänzung (NE) ist, welches ist dann die NE in den folgenden Sätzen und warum?

   > Weil Leute Geld verdienen wollen, wird gearbeitet.
   >   Heute wird hier gearbeitet.
   >   Hier wird heute gearbeitet.
   >   Gerannt wird hier nicht.
   >   Den Fleißigen wird gegeben.

   Wenn der Teil in Pos. 1 immer eine NE ist, warum dann trägt er Nominativ im Namen, obgleich er nichts mit dem Nominativ zu tun hat, außer die Möglichkeit auf Position 1 zu stehen?
2. Wenn die NE nichts mit diesem Subjekt-freien Passiv zu tun hat, gibt es eine Erklärung, warum das Subjekt fehlt und warum die 3. Person Singular benutzt wird?
   Und gibt es einen Namen für das Dummy-*es,* das man an Position 1 einfügen kann?
   Ist dieses grammatische Phänomen dasselbe, wie das, das hinter „Mir ist kalt“ steckt?

Ich weiß, das sind viele Fragen, aber ich kann im Web nichts finden.

Comment: "Hier wird gearbeitet." "Gerannt wird hier nicht." "Pardon wird nicht gegeben." Gemeinsam ist diesen Sätzen etwas Grimmiges, ja Brutales. Ist es das Kategorische? "Widerspruch wird nicht geduldet." Nur meine Einbildung, oder lassen sich auch heiter klingende Sätze bilden? "Hier wird gefeiert." Funktioniert nicht wirklich, oder?

Comment: „Jetzt wird gefeiert!“ Funktioniert prima.

Comment: @Eugene Seidel: stimmt schon, schön ist anders. Ich hab' es immer gehasst, wenn meine Mutter gesagt hat "Jetzt wird geschlafen!"... aber "Jetzt wird gefeiert" klingt für mich auch positiv :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zu 1. Die Erklärung ist natürlich Unfug. Erstens gibt es überhaupt kein `mit etw. sparen`, zweitens wäre es aufgrund der Präposition `mit` eine Dativergänzung. Richtig würde der Satz lauten:

> Wasser muss gespart werden.

Und dann wäre `Wasser` das Subjekt (im Nominativ) in diesem Passivsatz.

Zu 2. Die Erklärung für das fehlende Subjekt in deinem Ausgangsbeispiel ist, wie du richtig ausgeführt hast, dass vom Aktiv nichts übrig ist, was ein Subjekt sein könnte. Ein Passivsatz benötigt im Deutschen kein Subjekt.

Warum 3. Person Singular? Ist halt so. Möglicherweise kommt es von den Alternativkonstruktionen mit `man` oder `es`, die 3. Person Singular sind.

Das `Es` ist ein [Expletivum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum).

Comment: Ich denke schon, daß „mit etwas sparen“ geht. Möglicherweise ist es regional. Hier ein Beleg aus Bayern: [„Sparen oder nicht sparen mit Wasser?“](http://www.br.de/radio/bayern1/inhalt/experten-tipps/wasser-sparen-umwelt100.html)

Comment: Idiomatischer wäre wohl entweder "mit ... geizen" -- "Mit Wasser wird gegeizt" -- oder "an ... sparen" -- "An Wasser wird gespart".

Comment: _Sparsam mit Wasser umgehen_ ist wieder standardsprachlich.

Comment: @chirlu Das stimmt, aber ist ja auch ein anderes Verb.