# Was ist »Es« im Satz »Es fährt ein Zug um 14.45 Uhr«?

Tags: grammar

Ich lerne Deutsch und habe den Satz:

> Es fährt ein Zug um 14.45 Uhr

Was ist »Es«?

Comment: It is a more specific version of "Es gibt" see also [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3178) for an example with cars

Comment: @Harald, vielen Danke!! :)

Comment: Ein formales Subjekt. http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzglied/Subjekt.html#Anchor-Formales-14210

Comment: @CarstenSchultz, vielen Danke!! :)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Der Link zum [Platzhalter-es](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-es.html#Anchor-es-11481) hätte hier noch besser gepasst; schließlich gibt es ja ein Subjekt im Satz (ein Zug).

Comment: Richtig, Danke! Wieder etwas gelernt hier, wie schon früher das mit dem formalen Subjekt.

Comment: Related: [Why “es” exists in “Ihm war es nicht kalt.”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/17283/1224) und [Mit oder ohne “es”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7825/1224) – Die Frage [Nominativ-Ergänzung und Passiv](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7089/1224) behandelt das Thema auch am Rande.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... es ist hier kein formales Subjekt sondern einfach nur "filler"

Comment: @Harald... no it isn't. The "es" in "es gibt" remains if you flip word order "In Berlin gibt es..." The one in the example here disappears "Ein Zug fährt..."

Comment: @Emanuel, ja, Danke, hat Chris auch schon bemerkt.

Comment: @Emanuel Danke für den Hinweis! Ich lasse meinen Kommentar vorerst stehen damit die Folge der Kommentare noch einen Sinn ergeben.

Answer (score -1):

This "es" has the same function like "it" or "there" in english sentences like those:

> **It** rained cats and dogs. - **Es** regnete in Strömen.
>   **There** are no aliens. - **Es** gibt keine Außerirdischen.

It is just a surrogate for a subject, that is not specified.

Comment: Chris' hat doch schon in seinem Kommentar an mich darauf hingewiesen, dass dies nicht ganz der Funktion von „es“ in der Frage entspricht.

Comment: This is not true. "Es gibt in Berlin einen Turm". "In Berlin gibt es einen Turm" aber "Es fährt ein Zug um 10." "Ein Zug fährt um 10. " The two "es" have very little to do with one another. -1

Answer (score -1):

Im Grunde ist dieses "es" ein grammatischer Hinweis, dass das Subjekt nachgestellt ist. Dieses "es" ist also kein echtes Pronomen, das für ein Substantiv im Neutrum steht, sondern ein grammatisches Funktionswort.

Typischer Dialog am Fahrkartenschalter:
Gibt es einen Zug nach München, so zwischen vier und fÜnf?
Antwort: Ja, es fährt einer um 4 Uhr 15.

Hier stellt man das Subjekt gerne nach, weil es in der besonderen Stellung nach dem Verb mehr Gewicht hat und um die besondere Subjektstellung anzuzeigen, benutzt man "es".

Comment: Es kann auch ein grammatischer HInweis sein, dass das Objekt nachgestellt ist. Oder auch das garnichts nachgestellt ist "Es wird geschlafen". -1

Answer (score -3):

Stumpf gesagt ist "es" vergleichbar zu "it" im Englischen.

Hier ist "Es" aber kein spezieller Bezeichner für ein Objekt (das Auto fährt..., der Bus fährt...) sondern ein Objektübergreifender Bezeichner für alles was fahren kann.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist weit schwächer als die zuvor schon geschriebenen Kommentare. "Es" ist nicht "objektübergreifend", sondern ein Platzhalter für das später folgende "der Zug". Nicht mal der Vergleich mit dem englischen "it" stimmt, denn auf Englisch würde man eher sagen "**there** is a train at 4:45".